# Как правильно работать с regular expressions Groups с#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Имеется некоторое выражение (Например: 50,41+30,42 либо просто 50,41), то есть 2 числа (могут быть дробные/целые, положительные/отрицательные) и знак между ними (+/-), либо 1 число. Мне нужно вытащить числа и знак из этой строки и записать в разные переменные, пытаюсь делать это через группы, но что-то не получается:

```
string pattern = @"(-*[0-9]+,?[0-9]*)([\+\-]*)([0-9]+,?[0-9]*)";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

Match match = regex.Match(f);
MessageBox.Show(match.Groups[1].Value);
MessageBox.Show(match.Groups[2].Value);
MessageBox.Show(match.Groups[3].Value);
```

Подскажите в чем проблема, спасибо.

Comment: а для какой строки не получается? Для приведенной в вопросе _50,41+30,42_ результат корректный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте этот шаблон:

```
(-?[\d]+(?:[,|\.][\d]+)?)(?:[ ]*([+|-|\*|/])[ ]*(-?[\d]+(?:[,|\.][\d]+)?))?
```

Вот такие строки захватывает (проверено [здесь](http://www.regexr.com/)):

```
 -50,41 + 30,42
 50 + 30
 -5 * -1
 4/0.02
 40
 57,3
 -50.05
```

Comment: все работает, спасибо

Comment: Regexr не поддерживает регулярные выражения .NET. `\d` в .NET также найдет  [`вот такие значки`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28-%3f%5b%5cd%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5b%2c%7c%5c.%5d%5b%5cd%5d%2b%29%3f%29%28%3f%3a%5b+%5d*%28%5b%2b%7c-%7c%5c*%7c%2f%5d%29%5b+%5d*%28-%3f%5b%5cd%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5b%2c%7c%5c.%5d%5b%5cd%5d%2b%29%3f%29%29%3f&i=%d9%a2%d9%a3%d9%a4%d9%a5%d9%a6%d9%a7%d9%a8%d9%a9%db%b0%db%b1%db%b2%db%b3%db%b4%e0%af%a6%e0%af%a7%e0%af%a8%e0%af%a9%e0%af%aa%e0%af%ab%e0%af%ac%e0%af%ad%e0%af%ae%e0%b1%ab%e0%b1%ac%e0%b1%ad%e0%b1%ae%e0%b1%af%e0%b3%a6%e0%b3%a7%e0%b3%a8%e0%b3%a9%e0%b3%aa%e0%b3%ab%e0%b3%ac).

Comment: Кроме того, `|` в символьных классах трактуется как буквальный символ ([демо](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28-%3f%5b%5cd%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5b%2c%7c%5c.%5d%5b%5cd%5d%2b%29%3f%29%28%3f%3a%5b+%5d*%28%5b%2b%7c-%7c%5c*%7c%2f%5d%29%5b+%5d*%28-%3f%5b%5cd%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5b%2c%7c%5c.%5d%5b%5cd%5d%2b%29%3f%29%29%3f&i=1%7c2%2b2%7c5)).